# Opening the menu to the default value in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using `react-select` to allow the user to choose their birth year. If the user has already filled it in, it will be preset to some value, e.g. 1950. The input shows the correct value, however when the menu is opened it is scrolled to the top and shows the most recent years (2018, 2017, 2016, etc).

How do I get it to scroll down to 1950 and highlight that item by default?

My code:

```
class YearPicker extends React.PureComponent {
    options = [
        {label: 2018, value: 2018},
        {label: 2017, value: 2017},
        // ...
        {label: 1950, value: 1950},
        {label: 1949, value: 1949},
        // ...
    ]

    render () {
        return (
            <Select
                options={this.options}
                value={this.props.value}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/32pwzwxom)—this should default to 2002. Once you select a value (2002 or otherwise) it works fine, but when the page first loads you have to scroll down within the menu to find the value.

Per [the docs](https://react-select.com/) I have tried `value` and `defaultValue` as well as `selectedOption` but nothing seems to work. I created a very hacky workaround by leveraging `onMenuOpen` to find the correct DOM element after it's rendered and then scroll to it, however this breaks the functionality of the arrow keys.

Comment: possible to add a jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/32pwzwxom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at their source code and actually, you are doing everything right. The issue is in the following line of their code in Select.js:

```
 const selectedIndex = menuOptions.focusable.indexOf(selectValue[0]);
```

Here they are determining the index of the default option using indexOf and comparing objects. Object equality is performed by reference and not by value. So when you initialize the component for the first time and you explicitly provide an object, the equality fails. Wrong option is highlighted only for the first time. Rest of the times, object equality works since they extract the selected object out of the options and indexOf works

Check the working fork https://codesandbox.io/s/0xzmy6wvln

What I have done is created a function that extracts the selected option from the options array and passes that and so the equality works even for the first time.

I would encourage you to raise this issue on their repo and try to get it fixed.

Comment: Thank you! I did open an issue: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2906 . BTW I think there is some mutation going on in your example. Notice that you are not actually returning `index` from `determineIndex()` and that it doesn't work if you use `this.props.options` instead of `this.options`.

Comment: You are right, i was not returning the value. Check updated sandbox

Comment: Yes, I fixed that in my own implementation already. But it's a bit strange that it worked without the return.

Answer (score 3):

Set the default value to the object from the options menu.

```
<Select
    options={this.options}
    defaultValue={this.options.find(option => option.value === this.props.value)}
/>
```

This is a workaround for the bug that @cdoshi described.